# How to verify for counter signed XML document?

Tags: xml-signature, xades4j

How to verify the use library `Xades4j` for counter signed xml document.
Iam getting the following error when verifying with `Xades4j` :

> xades4j.verification.CounterSignatureSigValueRefException:
>   Verification failed for property 'CounterSignature': the counter
>   signature doesn't reference the SignatureValue element of the
>   countersigned signature   at
>   xades4j.verification.CounterSignatureVerifier.verify(CounterSignatureVerifier.java:75)
>     at
>   xades4j.verification.CounterSignatureVerifier.verify(CounterSignatureVerifier.java:37)
>     at
>   xades4j.verification.GenericDOMDataVerifier.verify(GenericDOMDataVerifier.java:65)
>     at
>   xades4j.verification.GenericDOMDataVerifier.verify(GenericDOMDataVerifier.java:30)
>     at
>   xades4j.verification.QualifyingPropertiesVerifierImpl.verifyProperties(QualifyingPropertiesVerifierImpl.java:59)
>     at
>   xades4j.verification.XadesVerifierImpl.verify(XadesVerifierImpl.java:187)
>     at
>   com.fit.einvoice.ingcountersigner.service.xades.XadesVerifyOperation.verifySignature(XadesVerifyOperation.java:92)
>     at
>   com.fit.einvoice.ingcountersigner.service.xades.XadesVerifyOperation.verifySignature(XadesVerifyOperation.java:87)
>     at
>   com.fit.einvoice.ingcountersigner.service.xades.XadesVerifyOperation.verifySignature(XadesVerifyOperation.java:64)

My validation function :

```
static void checkSigned(File file) {
     InputStream inputStream = null;
     try {
         inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
         XadesVerifyOperation verifyOperation = new XadesVerifyOperation();
         ArrayList<XadesVerificationResults> results = verifyOperation.verifySignature(inputStream);
            System.out.println("results size: " + results.size());
            for (XadesVerificationResults result : results) {
                System.out.println(result.SigningCertificate.getIssuerDN());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }
      }
 }
```

EDIT:

My counter signed function :

```
public void CounterSign() throws TransformerFactoryConfigurationError, Exception {
        Document doc = SignatureServicesBase.getDocument(_inputStream);
        Element sigElem = (Element) doc.getElementsByTagNameNS(Constants.SignatureSpecNS, Constants._TAG_SIGNATURE).item(0);

        System.out.println(sigElem.getNodeName());

        org.apache.xml.security.Init.init();
        XMLSignature xmlSig = new XMLSignature(sigElem, doc.getBaseURI());

         //Create counter signer
        XadesBesSigningProfile signingProfile = new XadesBesSigningProfile(new Pkcs11KeyingDataProvider(_certInfo));
        signingProfile.withAlgorithmsProvider(Sha1AlgProvider.class);
        signingProfile.withBasicSignatureOptionsProvider(new MyBasicSignatureOptionsProvider(true, true, false));
        final XadesSigner counterSigner = signingProfile.newSigner();

        //Extend with counter signature
        XadesFormatExtenderProfile extenderProfile = new XadesFormatExtenderProfile();
        XadesSignatureFormatExtender extender = extenderProfile.getFormatExtender();
        List unsignedProps = Arrays.asList(new CounterSignatureProperty(counterSigner));
        extender.enrichSignature(xmlSig, new UnsignedProperties(unsignedProps));

        SignatureServicesBase.outputDocument(doc, _outStream);

        if (!_isStream) {
            _inputStream.close();
            _outStream.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understood your question. If you're asking how to verify a counter signature property, it is already done as part of the verification of the "main" signature. Please note:

- The same `XadesVerifier` is used for both the main signature and the counter signature.
- If the validation succeeds, a property of type `CounterSignatureProperty` is added to the result.
- You can access the property [through the verification result](http://xades4j.googlecode.com/svn/release/1.3.0/javadoc/reference/xades4j/verification/XAdESVerificationResult.html#getPropertiesFilter%28%29) of the main signature

  ```
  XAdESVerificationResult res = ...;
  CounterSignatureProperty p =  res.getPropertiesFilter().getOfType(CounterSignatureProperty.class);
  ```

EDIT:

The message says everything: the counter signature is probably invalid. By definition, a counter signature must include a reference to the countersigned `SignatureValue` element.

Can you lookup the CounterSignature element on the original XML document and post it here?

Comment: Thanks for answer. Countersigned xml file : https://www.dropbox.com/s/xwsmstp809y33de/countersigned.xml  first signed original file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xiy99o06d3m8lqy/signed.xml

Comment: Did you change the lib code on how the data object references are added to the signature? There is a "xml-c14n11#WithComments" transform on the counter signature reference to the main signature's SignatureValue element. By default this shouldn't be added.

Anyway, I think the cause of the exception is that, currently, the verification of the counter signature assume that dereferencing SignatureValue ref results on a XML node. With the canonicalization, that's not true. I need to check that it is exactly the same node, which means it is not safe to allow transforms.